# Scikit SGDClassifier using letters as features instead of words

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, scikit-learn

I'm trying to classify phrases using the SGDClassifier following [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html) tutorial

My pipeline looks like this:

```
p_clf = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=(1, 2),
                                  token_pattern=r'\b\w+\b', min_df=1)),
                  ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
                  ('clf', SGDClassifier(loss='log', penalty='l2',
                                        alpha=1e-3, n_iter=5, random_state=42)), ])
```

Even though I'm getting the right classification, I don't understand why it treats letters as features instead of the entire word. In this example when I call `predict_proba('Hello')` I get:

```
[[ 0.15889614  0.23752053  0.4353584   0.16822494]
 [ 0.15889614  0.23752053  0.4353584   0.16822494]
 [ 0.15889614  0.23752053  0.4353584   0.16822494]
 [ 0.15889614  0.23752053  0.4353584   0.16822494]
 [ 0.11579265  0.19786962  0.36811551  0.31822223]]
```

Where each row is a letter and the columns are my classes.
Shouldn't it be just one row?

Comment: `'Hello'` is maybe interpreted as an array/list like ['H','e','l','l','o']. What happens if you use `predict_proba(['Hello'])`?

Comment: That solved it! Thank you !

Comment: Good, glad I could help. I'll just write it as an answer so that this question has an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case `'Hello'` is interpreted as an array of characters like `['H','e','l','l','o']`. (Remember that `predict_proba` expects an array or a sparse matrix as input.) This can be solved by putting the string in a list:

```
predict_proba(['Hello'])
```